# Number of columns per row in responsive grid

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way of working out how many columns are in each row? Based on the responsive viewport and without changing the html.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">.col-xs-6 .col-lg-4</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-10">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-10</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-10">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 col-lg-10</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 col-md-2</div>
</div>
```

E.g: number of columns per row

```
Default (XS) 
1
2
2
2

Medium
2
1
1
3

Large
2
1
1
1
2
```

Example large viewport with 5 rows
[image]
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGwdmO

Comment: sorry, its unclear to me.

Comment: I want to calculate how many columns in a row based on the viewport size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to 'calculate' it. What comes to mind:

```
var columns = [1, 2, 2, 2]; // default

var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

if (viewportWidth >= 1200){ // large
    columns = [2, 1, 1, 1, 2];
}
else if (viewportWidth >= 992) { // medium
    columns = [2, 1, 1, 3];
}
```

To respond to window resize event, you can subscribe to

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   ...
});
```