# Bootstrap grid with different height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I must be this grid with bootstrap.

[image: grid with different height]

Comment: that is not really in a grid more of a table. not sure that can be easily done using bootstrap. Is there a reason you have to use bootsrap grid?

Comment: You can't use Bootstrap columns like that; they have to be in rows: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid You might be able to use something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to get that layout.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314766/number-of-columns-per-row-in-responsive-grid) may help you. But I prefer you to use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I find a solution with jquery script.